# How to get element from std::tuple by type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a set of classes A, B, C and I want to have access instances of them from generic code by type, f.e

```
template<typename T>
newObject()
{
    return m_storage->getNew();
}
```

where m_storage is instance of A or B or C, depends on T.

So I came up with std::tuple, but there is the problem because I can't get element from tuple by type.

```
std::tuple<A,B,C> m_tpl;
template<typename T>
newObject()
{
    return m_tpl.get<T>().getNew();
}
```

Is there any way to do it?Is this possible?

Thanks.

PS:
I don't want to write the specialisation of newObject for each type.:-)

Comment: If you need to have only one of either A, B or C, you should use `boost::variant` rather than `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3584.html) is a draft from C++14 about getting value from tuple by type.

But before C++14 will come, you could write something like below:

```
namespace detail
{

template <class T, std::size_t N, class... Args>
struct get_number_of_element_from_tuple_by_type_impl
{
    static constexpr auto value = N;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N, class... Args>
struct get_number_of_element_from_tuple_by_type_impl<T, N, T, Args...>
{
    static constexpr auto value = N;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N, class U, class... Args>
struct get_number_of_element_from_tuple_by_type_impl<T, N, U, Args...>
{
    static constexpr auto value = get_number_of_element_from_tuple_by_type_impl<T, N + 1, Args...>::value;
};

} // namespace detail

template <class T, class... Args>
T get_element_by_type(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    return std::get<detail::get_number_of_element_from_tuple_by_type_impl<T, 0, Args...>::value>(t);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 42;

    auto t = std::make_tuple(3.14, "Hey!", std::ref(a));

    get_element_by_type<int&>(t) = 43;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    // get_element_by_type<char>(t); // tuple_element index out of range

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From your code I'm guessing this only gets the *first* occurrence of the type? I am I right?

Comment: @0x499602D2, Exaclty. This is different from `std::get<T>` behavior.

Answer (score 5):

A simple variadic mixin container does the trick:

```
template < typename T > struct type_tuple_value 
{ 
    T value; 
    type_tuple_value ( T&& arg ) : value(std::forward<T>(arg)) {}
};

template < typename ...T > struct type_tuple : type_tuple_value<T>...
{
    template < typename ...Args > type_tuple ( Args&&... args ) :
    type_tuple_value<T>(std::forward<T>(args))... {}
    template < typename U > U& get() { return type_tuple_value<U>::value; }
    template < typename U > const U& get() const { return type_tuple_value<U>::value; }
};
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/KGVNbJ)

Comment: It is not exactly an answer to the original question (getting from std::tuple), but someone might find this also helpful and I like your C++11 solution :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also compute the position of the type with a constexpr function if you don't like template.

```
  constexpr int count_first_falses() { return 0; }

  template <typename... B>
  constexpr int count_first_falses(bool b1, B... b)
  {
    if (b1) return 0;
    else return 1 + count_first_falses(b...);
  }

  template <typename E, typename... T>
  decltype(auto) tuple_get_by_type(const std::tuple<T...>& tuple)    
  {
    return std::get<count_first_falses((std::is_same<T, E>::value)...)>(tuple);
  }
```

Comment: This code is C++14 code (since it uses deducted return types). In C++14 std::get already supports searches by element type.