# g++ and clang different behavior with recursive variadic template bitset creation (possible gcc bug?)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, bitset

The following code produces drastically different results when compiled with **g++** or with **clang++**. Sorry for the long example, but I haven't been able to make it any shorter.

The program should assign a specific bit position to a specific type, then build an `std::bitset` containing multiple type bits.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using Bts = bitset<32>;

int getNextId() { static int last{0}; return last++; }

template<class T> struct IdStore{ static const int bitIdx; };
template<class T> const int IdStore<T>::bitIdx{getNextId()};

template<class T> void buildBtsHelper(Bts& mBts) { 
    mBts[IdStore<T>::bitIdx] = true; 
}
template<class T1, class T2, class... A> 
void buildBtsHelper(Bts& mBts) { 
    buildBtsHelper<T1>(mBts); buildBtsHelper<T2, A...>(mBts); 
}
template<class... A> Bts getBuildBts() { 
    Bts result; buildBtsHelper<A...>(result); return result; 
}

template<class... A> struct BtsStore{ static const Bts bts; };
template<class... A> const Bts BtsStore<A...>::bts{getBuildBts<A...>()};
template<> const Bts BtsStore<>::bts{};

template<class... A> const Bts& getBtsStore() { 
    return BtsStore<A...>::bts; 
}

struct Type1 { int k; };
struct Type2 { float f; };
struct Type3 { double z; };
struct Type4 { };

int main()
{
    cout << getBtsStore<Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- **g++ 4.8.2** prints-----:    `00000000000000000000000000000001`
- **clang++ SVN** prints:   `00000000000000000000000000001111` *(as expected)*

Only compilation flag is `-std=c++11`.

**What is happening? Am I introducing undefined behavior? Is g++ wrong?**

Comment: Regarding your stating that the "Only compilation flag is -std=c++11": While there may be none in this case, when you have a problem always enable as many warnings as you can.

Comment: While I don't know if it's a bug, this program does not "assign a specific bit position to a specific type at compile-time", unless due to as-if rule. It works at initialization time. You can't use non-constexpr functions at compile time.

Comment: @zch: Yeah sorry, I used the wrong term. Fixing the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code relies on initialization order of two declarations:

```
template<class T> const int IdStore<T>::bitIdx{getNextId()};

template<class... A> const Bts BtsStore<A...>::bts{getBuildBts<A...>()};
// getBuildBts uses IdStore<T>::bitIdx as indexes to assign
```

If all of `IdStore<T>::bitIdx` initializations happen before `BtsStore<A...>::bts` then you get your expected behavior. If all of the happen after `BtsStore<A...>::bts` then you get g++ behavior. Both orderings are allowed by standard:

> **3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables**
>
> 2 (...) Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is either ordered or unordered. Definitions of explicitly
>   specialized class template static data members have ordered
>   initialization. **Other class template static data members (i.e.,
>   implicitly or explicitly instantiated specializations) have unordered
>   initialization**.

Comment: Thank you. How can I force `IdStore<T>` to initialize before everything else?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I've posted an asnwer to your new question.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, I would do this actually in compile time, but that might be a bit advanced. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707645/how-to-get-element-from-stdtuple-by-type

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594002/for-stdtuple-how-to-get-data-by-type-and-how-to-get-type-by-index?rq=1

Comment: Accepted this answer as it directly replies to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to make `IdStore::bitIdx` a static member function returning a static local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to zch's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565257/1137388).

Forcing the instatiations of `IdStore` for `Type1`, `Type2`, `Type3` and `Type4` just after these types are defined, *seems* to fix the problem. For this, add these lines just after the definitions of `Type1`, `Type2`, `Type3` and `Type4`.

```
template struct IdStore<Type1>;
template struct IdStore<Type2>;
template struct IdStore<Type3>;
template struct IdStore<Type4>;
```

**Update**: Like Vittorio, I no longer like the solution above. Here is another one. Turn `IdStore` into a template function:

```
template <typename T>
int IdStore() {
    return getNextId();
}
```

and, in `buildBtsHelper` use it this way:

```
mBts[IdStore<T>()] = true;
```

Comment: I don't really like this solution as the system is intended to be used for a component-based game entity system, where there are about 30-40 types... and it seems annoying for the user having to define all of those types

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Neither do I ;-) So I came up with something that I find better (see the update). It uses an old trick which is replacing a static variable by a function that returns a local static variable (here it's done indirectly through `getNextId`). In this way we're sure that the value is initialized at the first time it's used.

Comment: Make it `static id = getNextId(); return id;` and it could do as a workaround, I guess.

Comment: @zch: This is the solution I'm now using - seems to work. Thanks everyone.