# Imitating dynamic polymorphism with CRTP + variadic templates

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, tuples, crtp

I need to replace dynamic polymorphism in a code with fairly big classes and I'm having problems with a CRTP + variadic templates design.

To illustrate, I provide a toy problem below.

There is a dynamically polymorphic class such that the following interface is used:

```
int main() { 
  Loop loop;
  Add add ;
  loop.set(add);
  loop.run();
  Sub sub ;
  loop.set(sub); 
}
```

Of course, `Sub` and `Add` are derived from a base class `Operation` and `op(double & v)` is a virtual method.

**I need to keep this interface** for other reasons, while changing dynamic by static polymorphism, this is my solution until now:

```
template <typename T> class Operation { 
public: 
  double d=1.;
  void op(double & d) { static_cast<T*>(this)->op(d);}
};
class Add final: public Operation<Add> { 
public: void op(double & v) { v += d; }
};
class Sub final: public Operation<Sub> {
public: void op(double & v) { v -= d; }
};
```

and for the `Loop` class:

```
template <typename... Types>
class MetaLoop {
public:
  double d = 0 ;
  template <typename T> void set(T & t) { 
  std_cxx17::get<std::vector<T*> >(data).push_back(&t) ; 
  }
  template <typename T> void run() { 
    for (auto j = 0; j<2E9 ; ++j)
      std_cxx17::get<std::vector<T*> >(data).back()->op(d);
    std::cout << d << std::endl; 
  }
private:
  std::tuple<std::vector<Types*>... > data ;
};
typedef MetaLoop<Add,Sub> Loop ;
```

`std_cxx17::get<T*>(data)` is a call to a method selecting elements in a tuple by type, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707645/how-to-get-element-from-stdtuple-by-type)

This solution, however requires *almost* the interface I want except for the need to provide the template argument to `run()`, i.e. `run<Add>` and `run<Sub>` and the need to *register* `Add` and `Sub` to `MetaLoop` in `typedef MetaLoop<Add,Sub> Loop`

I would like to know if it is possible, without using macros, to:

1. Register the `Operation<T>` classes to `MetaLoop` automatically (i.e. automatically call `typedef Metaloop<...operations...>`)
2. Avoid providing the template class to the `run` method. (i.e. call `run()` instead of `run<Add>()`)
3. Get this methods from a library: Isn't there a library (e.g. Boost) which can provide this kind of polymorphism statically?

Please keep in mind that I am aware that there are several other architectures I can use, but there are many other constraints I have to play with. This is just a toy problem to exemplify.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

Question 2 has been answered! See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e68ea7faabba3e40

Kudos to https://www.reddit.com/user/17b29a

Comment: What do you expect it to run if you don't specify explicitly `Add`? Should it run both `Add` and `Sub`?

Comment: I expect for it to run the last type that has been set. Thanks!

Comment: So, you expect to have only one active type each time? Why do you store everything in a vector thus?

Comment: Excellent question! Thanks for answering!
I store everything in a vector because I expect to store more than one instantiation of `Add` for instance.

Comment: Ok, but if your concern is to use ever and only the last one, why do you keep track of the others? Can't you simply replace the active one? (I'm asking to be able to give you a proper answer).

Comment: I need to keep track of the others because I may want to set a previous instantiation of `Add`, in which case I would have to compare before executing `run()`. I hope that it can still be performed statically.

Answer (score 0):

You can *type-erase* your types as in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct Operation {
    void op(double &d) { static_cast<T*>(this)->op(d) ; }
    double d{1};
};

struct Add: Operation<Add> {
    void op(double &v) { v += d; }
};

struct Sub: Operation<Sub> {
    void op(double &v) { v -= d; }
};

class Loop {
    using Fn = void(*)(double &, void *);

    template<typename T>
    static void op(double &d, void *op) {
        static_cast<T*>(op)->op(d);
    }

public:
    template<typename T>
    void set(T &t) {
        data.emplace_back(&op<T>, &t);
    }

    void run() {
         auto &p = data.back();
         for(auto j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
             p.first(d, p.second);
         }

         std::cout << d << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::pair<Fn, void*>> data;
    double d = 0;
};

int main() {
    Loop loop;
    Add add;
    loop.set(add);
    loop.run();
    Sub sub;
    loop.set(sub);
    // ...
}
```

Note also that, in this case, the CRTP idiom is useless and you can drop the template class `Operation`.
Simply define `Add` and `Sub` as it follows:

```
struct Add {
    void op(double &v) { v += d; }
    double d{1};
};

struct Sub {
    void op(double &v) { v -= d; }
    double d{1};
};
```

If you want to differentiate between `Add` and `Sub` and provide different algorithms, you can use specializations.
As an example:

```
class Loop {
    using Fn = void(*)(double &, void *);

    template<typename T>
    static void op(double &d, void *op);

public:
    template<typename T>
    void set(T &t) {
        data.emplace_back(&op<T>, &t);
    }

    void run() {
        auto &p = data.back();
        for(auto j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            p.first(d, p.second);
        }

        std::cout << d << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::pair<Fn, void*>> data;
    double d = 0;
};

template<>
void Loop::op<Add>(double &d, void *op) {
    Add *add = static_cast<Add*>(op);
    // do whatever you want with add
    add->op(d);
}

template<>
void Loop::op<Sub>(double &d, void *op) {
    Sub *sub = static_cast<Sub*>(op);
    // do whatever you want with sub
    sub->op(d);
}
```

Note that the solution matches all the requirements listed in the question and it works with the `main` provided as an example by the OP.

Comment: Thanks @skypjack !
Unfortunately my objects `Add` and `Sub` are much more complex than it is shown in my example and what I do with them in Loop is also much more complex than shown. Therefore, I really need to access to pointers to them.

I got an answer to fix the interface that I think it is quite neat! I just need a way now to instantiate all `Operation<T>` specializations and all would be solved! :-)

Comment: @Astor In my example you actually _accessing_ to a pointer to them. See the implementation of the `op` method in `Loop`, it casts the objects back to their origins types.

Comment: @Astor Added more details to the answer. Let me know if it's clear. You can still use CRTP if you want, even though it is not strictly required in this case.

Comment: You do, but I would have to store as much `Fn` functions as member functions my `Operation<T>` has, but the most important thing is not that but the fact that I have to keep a static code and in your example (as far as my compiler is concerned) a pointer is being dereferenced in each call to `p.first(d, p.second)` like in a dynamically polymorphic code. When iterating 2E9 times, it is performing 3 times slower.
Huge thanks though, honestly! I should have been more clear with my specs.

For the moment I just need to find a way to register all `Operation<T>` to MetaLoop...

Comment: @Astor You can move the loop _within_ the specialized functions and get a reference before to start it. Not a huge problem indeed. Anyway, it's your code, do as you prefer. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really!!